# encode in md5 a field of a form in cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a form on cloudpages, my question is if it is possible to be able to encode one of the fields in md5, to send it to the DE as subscriberkey.

I have tried javascript but I have problems because I cannot install the MD5 package to use it.

Comment: This might help ...... https://ampscript.guide/md5/

Answer (score 0):

Based on their [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityMD5.htm)

```
     Platform.Load('Core','1')

     var email = Request.GetFormField('NAME_OF_EMAIL_FIELD');
     var email_md5 = Platform.Function.MD5(email,"UTF-8");

     // ... insert into DE
```

Now MD5 is not the greatest as it's known that you can generate the same hash (although very unlikely). A more secure way would be to implement SHA256 with an SSJS/AMPScript mix.

```
     Platform.Load('Core','1')

     var email = Request.GetFormField('NAME_OF_EMAIL_FIELD');
     Platform.Function.TreatAsContent("%%[var @email_sha set @email_sha = SHA256('"+email+"','UTF-16')]%%");
     var email_sha = Variable.GetValue("@email_sha");


     // ... insert into DE
```

Note: I've done this in production before but my code here is untested as I'm writing this off the top of my head with their documentation.